# Throttle XDCR in couchbase

Tags: couchbase

If I have a cluster that is written to very often, and I only need that data replicated every so often.

1) Is it possible to throttle XDCR in couchbase at all?
2) Can I write a custom trigger for when XDCR should be attempted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to throttle XDCR in couchbase at all?

Yes, there are a number of settings to control XDCR, including reducing the number of "Replications per Bucket" from the default of 32 to something lower - this should reduce the XDCR bandwidth usage (at the expense of slower replication. See *Providing XDCR advanced settings* in the [Couchbase Admin Guide](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-admin/#admin-tasks-xdcr-advanced) for details on that and other settings.

> Can I write a custom trigger for when XDCR should be attempted?

No, this isn't possible at present (CB 2.5.1).